# How to fetch an array from a JSON String in Java?

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have a JSON string as below which I am obtaining from a web service call. How can I retrieve the array from the **builds** key.

```
 {
  "actions" : [
    {

    },
    null,
    {

    }
  ],
  "description" : "<a href=\"ws/product/target/product-10.7-SNAPSHOT.zip\" style=\"font-size: 50px\">Download Branch Build</a>",
  "displayName" : "EPIC-AUTODEV-8413",
  "displayNameOrNull" : null,
  "name" : "EPIC-AUTODEV-8413",
  "url" : "http://localhost:80/jenkins/view/Branch-Builds/job/EPIC-AUTODEV-8413/",
  "buildable" : false,
  "builds" : [
    {
      "number" : 71,
      "url" : "http://localhost:80/jenkins/view/Branch-Builds/job/EPIC-AUTODEV-8413/71/"
    },
    {
      "number" : 70,
      "url" : "http://localhost:80/jenkins/view/Branch-Builds/job/EPIC-AUTODEV-8413/70/"
    },
    {
      "number" : 69,
      "url" : "http://localhost:80/jenkins/view/Branch-Builds/job/EPIC-AUTODEV-8413/69/"
    },
    {
      "number" : 68,
      "url" : "http://localhost:80/jenkins/view/Branch-Builds/job/EPIC-AUTODEV-8413/68/"
    },
    {
      "number" : 67,
      "url" : "http://localhost:80/jenkins/view/Branch-Builds/job/EPIC-AUTODEV-8413/67/"
    },
    {
      "number" : 66,
      "url" : "http://localhost:80/jenkins/view/Branch-Builds/job/EPIC-AUTODEV-8413/66/"
    },
```

}

I tried with `tree=builds[*]`, but it gives me output like this

```
{"builds":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]}
```

Comment: which language you are trying ??

Comment: @PranayRana I m trying in Java.

Answer (score 0):

try out javascript method `JSON.parse`, below is example

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}');
```

the above will give you object and than you refer part you want.

and if you want your object convert back in to json than try `JSON.stringify()`

```
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
```